# grails display images in folder

Tags: image, grails, gsp

I'm trying to do a Grails webapp and now I'm trying to display all images in a folder.

To do that I have the following:

```
def display(){
        def dir = new File("/tmp/images")
        def list = []
        dir.eachFileRecurse() { file ->
            def avatarFilePath = new File(file.path)
            response.setContentType("application/jpg")
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(avatarFilePath.bytes);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

So using the code above I'm displaying one image using:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src='${createLink(controller: "images", action: "display")}' />
```

Using this code, I'm displaying one image.
How do I display all images in that folder?
Do I need to build a list? A list of what? A list of outputstream?
In that case, what should I put in my gsp file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the images folder was inside the app structure you could just create links to the image directly. In this case I think you need a controller action that output the contents of one file, and another action that get's the list of the images and request the file content.

```
class MyController {
  private static final File IMAGES_DIR = new File('/tmp/images')

  //get the list of files, to create links in the view
  def listImages() {
    [images: IMAGES_DIR.listFiles()]
  }
  //get the content of a image
  def displayImage() {
    File image = new File(IMAGES_DIR.getAbsoluteFilePath() + File.separator + params.img)
    if(!image.exists()) {
      response.status = 404
    } else {
      response.setContentType("application/jpg")
      OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
      out.write(avatarFilePath.bytes);
      out.close();
    }
  }

}
```

And your gsp could do something like

```
<g:each in="${images}" var="img">
  <img class="thumbnail" src='${createLink(controller: "myController", action: "displayImage", params:[img: img.name])}' />
</g:each>
```

P.S: the code is not tested, may need some adjust.

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't see where do you build a list of images.

Comment: `IMAGES_DIR.listFiles()` return the list of images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot see the link between listImages() and image() and img from the gsp page. Can you please explain it ? Thanks.

Comment: Let's say that his listimages is your display method. You return the list of images and you loop to display each image via a server side call to the 'image' action. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Ok, I changed the action to `displayImage`, hope this makes more clear the code :-)

Comment: What if I want from images outside from app folder? Like C:/images/?

Comment: @fsi just put your location inside `new File()`