# Display of image files using Grails

Tags: image, grails, plugins

My intention is to display images, which would have structure like: /images/username/. My intetntion is to keep "complete filename, eg path and file name" as String in database. I am using Grails 2.4.4...

I have read many contributions to this topic, finding no resolutions of my problem...

When I put image to the directory appname/web-app/images I can easily desplay it in .gsp with this command:

```
`<img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'image.jpg')}" alt="Image"/>
```

But when I try to create required structure, e.g. /images/username/ by
- defining subdirectory of appname/web-app/images/username
- deploying the file image.jpg in this directory
- using following command in gsp:

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/username', file: 'image.jpg')}" alt="Image"/>
```

Generated html link of the image points to localhost:8080/appname/images/username/image.jpg, but nothing is displayed

I made investigation, what is on application server, finding that, if I create subdirectory programmatically in controller:

```
def home (){
  def baseFolder = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/").getFile().toString()
  def imagesFolder = baseFolder + '/images/username'
  def tempFile=new File(imagesFolder)
  tempFile.mkdir()
....
```

and put the file image.jpg to this directory myslef, that gsp command:

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/username', file: 'image.jpg')}" alt="Image"/>
```

Grails displays the image

What I am doing wrong? How to display images in certain file system structure, which I would keep in database?

Is there only the way "through controller", like in: [grails display images in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841547/grails-display-images-in-folder)

Generally I would like to know you recommendation of really working "best practice" for image upload and display. From study of stackoverflow I understand that there are two approaches:
- keeping images in File system (low performance impact, security?, deployment?)
- keeping images in database (performance impact, reasonable security and deployment)
Which approach is better for application which will have thousands of images? Due to performance impact my view is first option, but I might be mistaken...

I undersatnd, that there are Grails plugins for image prosessing (Burning Image, ...). Due to high number of images in my application I will have to "standardize image size", e.g. reduce quality or size of some downloaded images.
Can you recommend me plugin to use? Would it be possible to provide link to "fully working example" of code, which uses this plugin?

Thank you very much for help and support

Comment: Here is something that will be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755341/dry-layouts-for-grails-emails/37764340#37764340 - you need to adopt that for your usage - I would say your approach is flawed - you are keeping user images on an accessible path- using the method discussed you can just stream the image from outside www location and display it using base64 image - it also covers image resize on the fly.. See if you can scrape out what you need from that - if you are struggling leave a comment and I will provide a howto as an answer later on tonight

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have tested my code on InteliJ Idea IDE, where everything was working as I expected. I was then elaborating, why I was not able to run successfully my code on GGTS, finding that I have to "Rebuild" the project once changing structure of image files location.